# Nuget update-package error with Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.JavaScript

Tags: azure, nuget, visual-studio-2015, azure-application-insights

Wether I start a new project and add Azure Application Insights or add Insights to an existing project, it seems to break my Nuget updates.

```
Attempting to resolve dependencies for multiple packages
update-package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.JavaScript'. Existing packages must be restored before 
performing an install or update.
At line:1 char:1
+ update-package
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

I can no longer just type 'update-package' to update all my packages.

Using VS2015

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the "Include Prerelease" option checked in the NuGet package manager (or specify `-IncludePrerelease` in the Update-Package command in the Package Manager Console)?

I believe the JavaScript package is only pre-release at this moment.